# chaining methods and selectors using jquery inside of a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to generate a chain of selectors and methods inside of a loop?

For example, I have an array of elements:

```
array[0] = '.type1value1, .type1value2, .type1value3';
array[1] = '.type2value1, .type2value2, .type2value3';
array[2] = '.type3value1, .type3value2, .type3value3';
```

I somehow need to build a chain of methods using the array elements as selectors (by looping or any other possible means!) so that I would end up with the following:-

```
$('.type1value1, .type1value2, .type1value3').filter('.type2value1, .type2.value2, .type2value3').filter('.type3value1, .type3value2, .type3value3');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you don't even need to do a loop:

```
var firstSelector = array.shift(); //returns first item in the array and removes it from the original array
var filterSelector = array.join(',');

$(firstSelector).filter(filterSelector);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you just do something like:

```
var $test = $(array[0]);

for (var i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
   $test =  $test.filter(array[i]);
}
```

Looking at your example, the value of each array element is exactly the value you want to pass as the selector parameter to `.filter()`

Answer (score 1):

use the following function to pass it an array of selectors...

```
function getSet(arrSet){
    var elements = $(arrSet[0]);
    for (var i = 1; i < arrSet.length; i++) {
        elements = $(elements).filter(arrSet[i]);
    }                       
}
```

Comment: `elements` is already a wrapped JQuery set so you don't need to `$()` wrap it to invoke `.filter`